# RxAlamofire - event on download completed missing

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I'm using RxAlamofire for downloading file. I have something like this:

```
let downloadResult = download(request, to: destination)
```

Unfortunately downloadResult observable doesn't emit next event on download completed, it only emits onCompleted.

I need next event when download is finished to flatMap to next request. At the moment I'm basing on progress (download progress >= 1) to emit the event I'm interested in.

But I feel that it's not the best solution, for now it works, however I'm afraid this aproach may fail in some situation.

Can you suggest something? Do I miss something in RxAlamofire download api?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Single<Void>.create { observer in
    return download(request, to: destination)
        .subscribe(onCompleted: {
            observer(.success(()))
        }, onError: {
            observer(.error($0))
        })
```